# Creating colorful text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a function that prints a certain text into a `<div id="1">` tag.

The string should mark certain index values in different color.

What I have written now is to go to all the index values I have and add a `<font color="color">` tag, and then I add it using `div1.innerHTML = result;`

Its a lot of work, and its very complicated. Is there another way that I can create a string
object like I've described without these HTML tags?

If I can do that then I would just use `div1.appendChild(String);`

Answer (score 6):

I generally am loathe to recommend that anybody use a library that they don't already claim to use, but this is one of those times where the question almost directly asks for a library as an answer :-)

Check out [Lettering.JS](http://letteringjs.com).  It was designed to do exactly what you describe. It wraps your text content by letter or by word or by line (I think) in `<span>` tags, under your control. You then use CSS to style elements, or some more JavaScript to manipulate and style the elements it creates for you.

Comment: Its an assignment, so I can't use it :(

Comment: Well, @yotamoo, you might want to check it out just to see how it does its thing. It's pretty simple code, really.

Answer (score 0):

if what your looking for is a syntax coloring, you can try this jQuery plugin.
http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/